# Should static_pointer_cast calls be std:: qualified, or relied upon ADL?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, pointer-conversion

`static_pointer_cast` resides in `std` namespace. Yet it takes pointers that are also in `std` namespace.

So both `std::` qualified calls and unqualified calls are accepted.

Which one is the right, more idiomatic way to call `static_pointer_cast`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if you know exactly which function you want to call, rather than allowing for customization, I would try to avoid ADL, implying avoiding unqualified calls.

In this case it is not expected for a library to provide its own `static_pointer_cast` for `shared_ptr`s of their own type. You always want to call the `std` version.
Calling `std::static_pointer_cast` directly guarantees that no other such `static_pointer_cast` will interfere.

If you include e.g. a library that also declared some function named `static_pointer_cast` which happens to be viable for your call and is a better fit or more specialized in overload resolution than the `std` one, you may accidentally call it instead if you use an unqualified call.

I think this is extremely unlikely to be a problem in the case of `static_pointer_cast`, because it is unlikely that a library will use that name in a way that the overload will be viable for a normal `std::static_pointer_cast` call and be at the same time a better match, all of it without realizing the implications.

But for example for `std::launder` this seems to have happened in some code bases (the other way around) when C++17 was introduced and the `std` overload turned out to be a better match than the library one in an unqualified call with a standard library type as argument.

If you look at for example C++ standard library implementations you will see that they follow this rule to avoid unqualified calls very strictly and use them only where the standard expects the user to be able to customize the call. Of course for non-library code especially this might not be as important of a consideration.

---

But also note that prior to C++20, if there is no function template named `static_pointer_cast` found by usual unqualified lookup, then an unqualified call using an explicit template argument list (which are required for `static_pointer_cast`) will fail anyway. So before C++20 you don't really have the choice to use the unqualified call without a prior `using` declaration to import the function.

Comment: "[...]  avoid ADL, implying avoiding unqualified calls" ... or introducing the convention of always calling as `(std::static_pointer_cast<Base>)(derived)` ;)

Comment: Can a function-template even be found by ADL prior to C++-20? For some reason I had it in my head that C++20 added this, but previously it was not considered viable -- hence why `std::get<...>` is required over just an ADL-found `get<...>`

Comment: @Human-Compiler Yes, correct. I have added a note at the end.

Comment: @user17732522 (W.r.t. to your first-then-deleted comment: a paranthesized unqualified-id is no longer an unqualified-id and ADL does not apply). It was an attempt at a joke to the "avoid ADL" statement.

Comment: @dfrib Ah ok, I see, that went right over my head.